# exception when trying to call webservice

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am getting the below exception when trying to call service from `SOAPUI`. When I open the endpoint in browser, it displays the wsdl fine.

```
WARN  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/}PaidClaimFacadeService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Message part {http://contract.premsisc.uss`enter code here`t.com/}findPaidClaims was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:194)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:188)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

My wsdl as in WAS 7 server

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="PaidClaimFacadeService" targetNamespace="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/">
<xs:element name="findPaidClaims" type="tns:findPaidClaims"/>
<xs:element name="findPaidClaimsResponse" type="tns:findPaidClaimsResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="findPaidClaims">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Product" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="findPaidClaimsResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="PremDiscountService" type="tns:PremDiscountService"/>
<xs:complexType name="PremDiscountService">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="findPaidClaims">
<wsdl:part element="tns:findPaidClaims" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="PremDiscountServiceException">
<wsdl:part element="tns:PremDiscountService" name="PremDiscountServiceException"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="findPaidClaimsResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:findPaidClaimsResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="PaidClaimFacade">
<wsdl:operation name="findPaidClaims">
<wsdl:input message="tns:findPaidClaims" name="findPaidClaims"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:findPaidClaimsResponse" name="findPaidClaimsResponse"></wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault message="tns:PremDiscountServiceException" name="PremDiscountServiceException"></wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="PaidClaimFacadeServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:PaidClaimFacade">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="findPaidClaims">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="findPaidClaims">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="findPaidClaimsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="PremDiscountServiceException">
<soap:fault name="PremDiscountServiceException" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="PaidClaimFacadeService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:PaidClaimFacadeServiceSoapBinding" name="PaidClaimFacadePort">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:9084/premdisc/services/PaidClaimFacadeService"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My Soap Request in `SOAPUI` :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:con="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:findPaidClaims>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Product>abc</Product>
      </con:findPaidClaims>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Soap Response in Soap UI:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Message part {http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/}findPaidClaims was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is how I configured the jaxws:endpoint

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="paidClaimWs" implementor="#paidClaimFacadeImpl"
        address="/PaidClaimFacadeService" wsdlLocation="/wsdl/PaidClaimFacade.wsdl"
        serviceName="msg:PaidClaimFacadeService" endpointName="msg:PaidClaimFacadePort"
        xmlns:msg="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/">
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: Have you checked your headers or content-negotiation methods?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This means that you are calling an operation which does not exits in your `WSDL` file.

```
{http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/}findPaidClaims was not recognized
```

This is your target name space: `http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/`
And this is your operation: `findPaidClaims`

If you'll check your `WSDL` you will see that there is no such operation like: `findPaidClaims`.

**EDIT**

Now the problem is clear. Your namespaces in WSDL file are wrong.
This is fixed WSDL and it will work. I don't know if you run some validation of your WSDL file, but my IntelliJ show the errors. So I fixed them:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://contract.premdisc.hcsc.com/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  name="PaidClaimFacadeService"
                  targetNamespace="http://contract.premdisc.hcsc.com/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                   xmlns:tns="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/types"
                   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
                   elementFormDefault="unqualified"
                   targetNamespace="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/types">
            <xs:element name="findPaidClaims" type="tns:findPaidClaims"/>
            <xs:element name="findPaidClaimsResponse" type="tns:findPaidClaimsResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="findPaidClaims">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Product" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="findPaidClaimsResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="PremDiscountService" type="tns:PremDiscountService"/>
            <xs:complexType name="PremDiscountService">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="findPaidClaims">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:findPaidClaims" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="PremDiscountServiceException">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:PremDiscountService" name="PremDiscountServiceException"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="findPaidClaimsResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:findPaidClaimsResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="PaidClaimFacade">
        <wsdl:operation name="findPaidClaims">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:findPaidClaims" name="findPaidClaims"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:findPaidClaimsResponse" name="findPaidClaimsResponse"></wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault message="tns:PremDiscountServiceException" name="PremDiscountServiceException"></wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="PaidClaimFacadeServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:PaidClaimFacade">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="findPaidClaims">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="findPaidClaims">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="findPaidClaimsResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="PremDiscountServiceException">
                <soap:fault name="PremDiscountServiceException" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="PaidClaimFacadeService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:PaidClaimFacadeServiceSoapBinding" name="PaidClaimFacadePort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9084/premdisc/services/PaidClaimFacadeService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The problem was that you had different namespace as your `xmlns:tns` and `targetNamespace`. Look closely at your WSDL.

```
xmlns:tns="http://contract.premdisc.hcsc.com/"
targetNamespace="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/"
```

You see that in your file they are different, but they must be the same. And for your XSD you need to use different namespace. Something like:

```
xmlns:tns="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/types"
```

As it was in your file:

```
xmlns:tns="http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/"
targetNamespace="http://contract.premdisc.hcsc.com/"
```

Ass you can see they are also different. Compare the file I fixed and your file and will see the difference. Try it with fixed file and it will work.

Comment: I do have an operation for **findPaidClaims** defined in the wsdl.

`<wsdl:portType name="PaidClaimFacade"> 
    <wsdl:operation name="findPaidClaims">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:findPaidClaims" name="findPaidClaims">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:findPaidClaimsResponse" name="findPaidClaimsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:PremServiceException" name="PremServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>`

Comment: Does your namespace: http://contract.premsisc.usst.com/ is pointing to that operation? Can you show the whole WSDL file, XSD schema and the SOAP request you are sending. Just edit your question and add those into it.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is quite old, but for some of you that stumble upon it: I've had the same problem, the cause? I had "old" WSDL loaded in my SOAPUI, while I changed some things in my "new" WSDL. Hence the problems, try reloading the WSDL in SOAPUI or deleting it and loading once again, then checking if you get the same error. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Check data format on route start. 
`<from id="_to2" uri="cxf:bean:yourServiceClient?dataFormat=RAW"/>`
Data formats RAW and MESSAGE possibly remove problem.