# Message part MyClass was not recognized. (Does it exist in service WSDL?)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to create a web service, and I create project based on a working project. It works with Storm and Boomerang-SOAP & REST Client.
Boomerang generate a request like that:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wse="http://wservices.yt/">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <wse:PerformTransaction>
            <request>
                <password>?</password>
                <username>?</username>
                <amount>0</amount>
                <parameters>
                    <paramKey>?</paramKey>
                    <paramValue>?</paramValue>
                </parameters>
                <serviceId>0</serviceId>
                <transactionId>0</transactionId>
                <transactionTime>2016-10-19T00:00:00</transactionTime>
            </request>
        </wse:PerformTransaction>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

and that is working normal, but I must get bellow request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:PerformTransactionArguments xmlns:ns1="http://wservices.yt/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:type="ns1:PerformTransactionArguments">
            <password>12345</password>
            <username>test</username>
            <amount>150000</amount>
            <parameters>
                <paramKey>customer_id</paramKey>
                <paramValue>6324357</paramValue>
            </parameters>
            <parameters>
                <paramKey>pin</paramKey>
                <paramValue>12345678</paramValue>
            </parameters>
            <serviceId>1</serviceId>
            <transactionId>437</transactionId>
            <transactionTime>2011-04-26T18:07:22</transactionTime>
        </ns1:PerformTransactionArguments>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I test with second request to web service it is keep getting error:

`Message part PerformTransactionArguments was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)`

In `wsdl` the class is written as `performTransactionArguments`. I have no idea how to solve this(is first time I came across with `soap`&`wsdl`) .  I have spent vainly about a week, so please, help to me solve the problem

I find many similar questions but I didn't find any solution.
one of them : [exception when trying to call webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040986/exception-when-trying-to-call-webservice)

If a piece of code or setting I can show, but now I don't know what to add here

Answer (score 3):

You're calling an operation(`PerformTransactionArguments`) which doesn't exist. The first query(`PerformTransaction`) works fine because you might already have it in your wsdl contract.